# Выполнение команд в консоли Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, cmd

**Здравствуйте!**

Как можно выполнить в консоли Windows сразу более одной команды? Пытался это сделать с помощью `WinExec()` , но не вышло. Хотелось бы узнать, как в таком случае можно выполнять более одной команды:

```
WinExec('cmd /c chcp 1251 systeminfo > C:\sysInfo.txt',1); // естественно нет!
```

**Благодарю!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделяйте команды парой амперсандов

```
echo Start && dir > thisfiles && echo End
```

Правда, если какая-либо из команд завершится неудачно, то цепочка прервется.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это мне очень пригодится!

Comment: Ну так чтоб не прерывалась, надо вместо `&&` (с проверкой) использовать `&` (без проверки)?